# How can I add items to my cart without making a JS object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

When I started the project, I never thought of adding a cart, but now I want to.
Let me tell you the structure,
I have a jsx called `Pricetag.jsx` in which I have defined how my card will look like it has `name`, `image`, and `add to cart`.

Here is my `Pricetag.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import './Body.css' 
// import './Cart.js'
import { useState } from 'react'
export default function Pricetag(props) {
  const [count, setCartCount] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card1">
        <div className="image">
          <img src={props.images} alt="" className='card-image' />
        </div>

        <div className="content">

          <div className="name">
            {props.name}
          </div>

        </div>
        <div className="button">
          <button  className='btn no1' id='cartbutton' onClick={() => setCartCount(count + 1)} >
            Add to cart 
          </button>
          <br></br>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is the `Birthday.jsx` where I have used Pricetag information using props,

import React from 'react'
import './Body.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Pricetag from './Pricetag'
import image80 from './assets/cake80.jpeg'
import image81 from './assets/cake81.jpeg'

```
export default function Cakebody(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <Link to='/' className="menulink con112 ">
                <div className='name1' >Back to home page</div>
            </Link>
            <div className="headingbody">
                {props.title}
            </div>
            <hr className='latestline' />
            <div className='container1'>
                <Pricetag images={image80} name="Doll Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
                <Pricetag images={image81} name="Mixed Platte Cake" bold="Rs 345" cut="Rs 634" />
            </div>            </>
    )
}
```

```
Now first I tried my self, then after watching some tutorials I noticed that they all are using objects to store data -> id, name, price, and all but, is there any way I can do it without it.

I want to some how grab the name and image of the cake from the birthday.jsx and want to send it to a new cart.jsx.
```

Comment: _"is there any way I can do it without it"_ - why? Objects are the bedrock of JavaScript.

Comment: This is comparable to trying to drive a Car without a Car.

Comment: ok, I will use objects only. Because I didn't know I will be using the cart and I didn't use objects that's why I was asking if it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

In fact JS is an object, everything in JS is kind of an object
if you find way to do something is JS without using object let me know